# Ajax error when sending data with Internet Explorer 11 - "SCRIPT65535 argument not optional"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a problem with sending data via **AJAX**,  It works on all browsers but on **IE 11** it gives an error.

This is my function `addToCart`.
There are some paramaters and one **JSON**.
When I try to send data, this error message comes out.

[image: IE 11 error SCRIPT65535 "non-optional argument"]

I tried to put the `cache=false` attribute to ajax too but nothing has changed.

```
function addToCart(productId, userId) {

var colorId = getColorId();

var jsonObj = [];

item = {}
item["Size"] = "M";
item["Quantity"] = parseInt(2);

jsonObj.push(item);

$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "post",
    url: "/Cart/AddToCart",
    contenttype: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    data: {
        "productId": productId, "color": colorId, "userId": userId, "sizesQty": jsonObj },
    beforeSend: function () {
        
    },
    success: function (data) {
        
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        
    }
})

}
```

Do you have any solutions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested with your code in IE 11 and reproduced the issue. I found that you didn't declare variable `item` in the function. IE is more strict to the grammar. After declaring the variable, it can work well in IE:

```
var item = {};
item["Size"] = "M";
item["Quantity"] = parseInt(2);
```

Comment: This is precisely the problem. I seemed to have tried to put `var` in it too but in the meantime who knows how many other things I had changed and it was no longer working. Thank you.